# Which Android Permission Would Be Needed to Run a SQLite3 Database Dump?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-permissions

I have code to dump a `sqlite3` database then read it into a string:

```
    String dbPath = "/data/data/com.company.project/databases/project.db";
    String outputPath = "/data/data/com.company.project/databaseDump.txt";

    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sqlite3 " + dbPath + " '.dump' > " + outputPath);
    proc.waitFor();
    returnString = FileUtil.getStringFromFile(outputPath);
```

When I run it on my emulator I'm fine, but when I run it on a real phone it doesn't work. I'm curious if I need to add additional permissions into the manifest, or what I'm missing.

**EDT**

So it seems part of my issue was a PEBKAC... I ran the dump manually through the adb and after that the reading of the file worked fine in the emulator. So the dump command does not look like it works from the emulator either... do I need to do an intent for the sqlite3 program? If so, how do I do it for a particular program?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `SQLite3` is a command you can run from the `adb`, but it is not necessarily on the phone. Based on that I took a different approach. I used android's DatabaseUtils to help me build the result I needed, e.g. `DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(cursor)`. I did this for each of the tables I was interested in and built a return string.

Comment: This is fundamentally mistaken.  Anything run from adb *is* run "on the phone".  Granted it is run under adb's userid rather than an application's, but provided that the source and destination files are owned by the application userid attempting to perform the operation (or globally accessible) that should not be a problem.  That said, launching a process is not a preferred way of doing things in an Android app.